# Trouble upgrading laptop processor to core 2 duo

Tags: laptop, cpu, upgrade, dell-inspiron

I own a Dell Inspiron 1545 that uses, I believe, a Pentium 4. I wanted to upgrade it, so I looked and found that the strongest processor the laptop officially supports is an intel core 2 duo T6600. I purchased one and installed it. However, when I subsequently turned it back on, it powered up and the fan started, but nothing displayed on the screen. Not even the BIOS came up. When I re-insert the old chip it works perfectly. Am I missing something? Do I need to install a driver for it first or something?

Comment: Both the motherboard and bios need to support the cpu, so look to see if there is an update for the bios, and if the release notes indicate what CPUs are supported.

Comment: My BIOS is the latest version. I can not find any kind of release notes on the BIOS, but I have seen examples of other people using the same processor with the same computer

Comment: Try doing a CMOS reset... I am not sure how this would be done on a laptop but I am sure there is a way, also, sometimes after changing a CPU I have had to re-seat RAM. Not sure why this is but it is...

Answer (score 0):

[According to this Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z95qviAR34A), you can upgrade to a [core 2 duo t7250](http://ark.intel.com/de/products/31728/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T7250-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB), which works fine. The T6600 seams to be too new for the laptop.